# C# - Receber dados via serial e pausar recebimento

Tags: c#

Ola

Eu estou desenvolvendo um software em C# que recebe dados via comunicação serial, esta tudo funcionando mas estou com um probleminha. Meu software recebe os dados via serial e exibe no Text Box, mas logo em seguinte os dados são deletados do Text Box, creio eu que seja devido ao Timer que eu inseri no Software para checar se algo foi recebido pela Serial. Eu gostaria de receber os dados e que eles permaneçam no Text Box, como consertar este problema ?

**Esta e a parte do código que recebe e exibe os dados:**

```
private void timerReceive_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (serialPort1.IsOpen == true)
        {
           if (serialPort1.ReadBufferSize >= 0)
           {
               RxString = serialPort1.ReadExisting();
               textBoxReceber.Text = RxString;

            }
        }
    }
```

Obrigado

Comment: Como você está verificando se o valor é igual a 0 (zero) então ele aceita e sobreescreve o valor do campo. deixa somente quando for maior que 0. `if (serialPort1.ReadBufferSize >= 0)`

Comment: Armazena o conteúdo em um escopo maior e vá concatenando

Answer (score 0):

Eu quero agradecer a ajuda e compartilhar como eu resolvi o problema no meu código.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O problema estava na minha variável **RxString** que esta dentro do **Timer**, que tem o objetivo em ficar atualizando e coletando tudo que for recebido pela serial, então se eu receber por exemplo a frase ( **Hello World** ) ele armazena na variável **RxString** e caso eu não receber **nada** ele também estava armazenando **vazio** em minha variável, então eu inseri o seguinte:

```
if(RxString != "")
{
  textBoxReceber.Text = RxString;
}
else
{

}
```

Ele verifica se a variável possui algum valor exibindo assim na TextBox, caso o valor seja **vazio**, não faz nada. Na realidade ele **não** estava **deletando** o conteúdo da TextBox, ele estava **exibindo** o **valor vazio** no Text Box. Agora esta tudo funcionando perfeitamente.

**Código Completo:**

```
private void timerReceive_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (serialPort1.IsOpen == true)
  {
    if (serialPort1.ReadBufferSize > 0)
    {
      RxString = serialPort1.ReadExisting();

      if(RxString != "")
      {
        textBoxReceber.Text = RxString;
        navegador.DocumentText = RxString;
      }
      else
      {

      }
    }
  }
}
```

Obrigado a todos.

Comment: Se testa `serialPort1.ReadBufferSize > 0` não necessita de testar `RxString != ""`

Comment: Então Ramaral eu testei aqui, mas não deu certo. Porque sera ?

Comment: Se alterar o código que colocou na pergunta, substituindo `>=` por `>`, não vejo razão para não dar certo.